# Only leave some tags in a html string using PHP

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am crawling a website with simple_html_dom and need the result that would be somewhere between ->innertext and ->plaintext.

For example, here is the source string:

`<span lang="EN-CA">[28]<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span><span lang="EN-CA">The Canadian trade-marks regime is national in
scope.  The owner of a registered trade-mark, subject to a finding of
invalidity, is entitled to the exclusive use of that mark in association with
the wares or services to which it is connected throughout Canada.  Section 19 of
the <i>Trade-marks Act</i> provides:</span>`

I need to get rid of the `span` tags but not their contents (unless the `span` only contains `&nbsp;`'s) but retain `<i>`, `<u>` and `<b>`'s

So the result I'd like to achieve here would be a string:

`[28] The Canadian trade-marks regime is national in scope.  The owner of a registered trade-mark, subject to a finding of invalidity, is entitled to the exclusive use of that mark in association with the wares or services to which it is connected throughout Canada.  Section 19 of the <i>Trade-marks Act</i> provides:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following lines of code:

```
<?php

$string = '<span lang="EN-CA">[28]<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&n
bsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></span><span lang="EN-CA">The Canadian tr
ade-marks regime is national in scope. The owner of a registered trade-mark, subject to a finding of invalidity, is entitled to the exclusive u
se of that mark in association with the wares or services to which it is connected throughout Canada. Section 19 of the <i>Trade-marks Act</i> 
provides:</span>';

// Remove attributes within the <span> tag, just for clarity's sake.
$string = preg_replace('/(<span ([^\>]+)>)/i', '<span>', $string);

// Remove any spans that only contain &nbsp;
$string = preg_replace('/<span>([ ]|&nbsp;)*<\/span>/i', '', $string);

// Replace any consecutive span (opening or closing) tags with a space, to make
// clear the separation between one span and the next.
$string = preg_replace('/<(\/)?span><(\/)?span>/i', ' ', $string);

// Remove any remaining any instances of opening or closing span tags.
$string = preg_replace('/<(\/)?span>/i', '', $string);

print $string;
```

Note that I added an `i` after the slash for each regular expression, which gives you a case-insensitive search.  That's just in case you have some code that is `<SPAN>` or `<span>` or even `<SpaN>`.

Granted, it's not a tightly compressed single line of regular expression code awesomeness.  But, I did it this way so that you can see the steps along the way.  You can put the `print $string;` line throughout to see the progression.  I was hoping this way of demonstrating the code to you would help you, in the long run, to get a better feel for how regular expressions and `preg_replace` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this .

```
echo stripcslashes('<span lang="EN-CA">[28]<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></span><span lang="EN-CA">The Canadian trade-marks regime is national in scope. The owner of a registered trade-mark, subject to a finding of invalidity, is entitled to the exclusive use of that mark in association with the wares or services to which it is connected throughout Canada. Section 19 of the <i>Trade-marks Act</i> provides:</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what strip_tags is for:

```
echo strip_tags('<span>strip me</span> <i>leave me alone</i>', '<i>');
//=> strip me <i>leave me alone</i>
```